# lists in ods template with XDocReport and freemarker

Tags: list, freemarker, openoffice.org, ods, xdocreport

Have a simple, ods template.
Just want to iterate a list and display the data in the columns

Is working in ODT format, where I have this in the first character of a table:

```
@table:table-row
[#list booksList! as book]

@/table:table-row
[/#list]
```

This is not working in ODS (not iterating the rows. Displays an empty cell and the text "@table:table-row".

For one row (without loop) the following freemarker tags in the ODS file , work fine:

```
First cell: [#list booksList! as book]${book.title}
Second cell: ${book.author}
Third cell: [/#list]
```

But these tags will fail if there are more than one itens (books)

How to create ODS templates with freemarker lists ?

Is it possible to add JOOScripts into ods files using Open Office?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XDocReport for ODS support was just a POC, so it doesn't work like ODT. I suggest you that you don't use it or contribute to this support to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

It works on ODS too. You have just skip @table:table-row

```
A17 [#list report.row as r]
B17 ${r.col0}
A18 [/#list]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWJc2.png)